# Why am I getting these errors in my AngularJS (TypeScript) component?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have AngularJS component in TypeScript **news.component.ts** that calls a **google.service.ts** to get news RSS via some service that converts XML to JSON (not important).

So I have this method in NewsComponent:

```
getNewsHeadlines(): any {
    this.googleService.getNewsHeadlines().then(headlines => {
        this.newsHeadlines = headlines;
        this.$scope.$apply();
    });
    return;
}
```

---

I have this model defined for each news item:

```
export interface NewsHeadline {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    description: string;
    link: string;
}
```

---

I have this method in GoogleService service:

```
getNewsHeadlines() {
    const feed = 'http://rss.newsru.com/top/big/';
    const url = 'https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=' + encodeURIComponent(feed);
    return this.$http.get(url).then((response: any) => {
        let items = response.data.items;
        let results = items.map(result => {
            let newsHeadline: NewsHeadline = {
                title: 'string',
                content: 'string',
                description: 'string',
                link: 'string'
            };
            return newsHeadline;
        });
        return this.$q.all(results);
    });
};
```

**Why do I keep getting these error messages in Chrome console?**

**Is my getNewsHeadlines method in GoogleService written correctly?**

[image]

**What does it mean, when I click on Error link, there is tons of humanly unreadable garbage, that doesn't explain anything.**

Comment: I believe that error is because you're doing `$scope.$apply()` when a digest cycle is already in progress. Angular's built-in services, including `$http` trigger digest cycles automatically. You do not have to do it in your code.

Comment: Yes, you are using `$scope.$apply()` unnecessarily. The `$http` service embeds digestion controls because it's inside angularjs context. You should use `$apply` in external emitters like events attached directly to the DOM for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method doesn't need $scope.$$apply. It is being handled by the httpservice, as is angular context.

This is how it should look like:

```
getNewsHeadlines(): any {
    this.googleService.getNewsHeadlines().then(headlines => {
        this.newsHeadlines = headlines;
    });
    return;
}
```